# Different values for same property in css class

Tags: css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass

In my application I have two different modules. Some of the classes of CSS, I have css class name same in both module, and name of property to be applied is same but the values for these properties differ in both modules.

eg this class is in some x module css file:

```
.date-section  
 padding-bottom: 20px 
 border-bottom: 1px solid #e2e4e6   
 margin-bottom: 20px,
```

and some other module y has its css as in

```
.date-section  
 padding-bottom: 35px   
 border-bottom: 1px solid #edddce  
 margin-bottom: 20px.
```

Is there any way that same property can be used but values should differ with respect to module? Could I use property values differently in same class and same property?

Comment: You could try target each instance with [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).

Comment: Specify your selectors to a deeper level for each module - eg `.module-x .date-section {}` and `.module-y .date-section {}`